# Compute any real number, given an uncountable set of real numbers?

Tags: real-numbers, computability, turing-machines

Given an uncountable set of real numbers $S$, for any real number $r$, is there a Turing machine that computes $r$ given an oracle for some countable subset of $S$?

If yes, then is there a Turing machine that computes $r$ given some finite subset of $S$?

Comment: There are problems with this. The elements of the oracle are reals and not naturals. The turing machine cannot ask the oracle anything cause it cant specify the infinite amount of info to define a real.

Comment: A Turing machine "computes" a number if, given an input tape with the Natural number $n$, it outputs the $n$th digit of the number.  Let the "oracle" for countably many real numbers be provided to the Turing machine in the form of an input tape that (after $n$ itself) contains all of the real numbers interlaced together.

Comment: Essentially what you are describing is that you have a countable number of oracles. One for each real. Because the machine can only access a finite amount of data at any one time.

Comment: Does the machine know what the different reals are ? Real number 1, number 2 etc ? (how could it be otherwise ?) Then I think the answer is yes.

Comment: Yeah, it does "know" what the different reals are.  They can be interlaced so that the machine can query for the $n$th digit of the $m$th real number.  I think the answer is "yes" too, but I'm having trouble proving it.  I looked at the Stone-Weierstrass theorem this morning, but I don't know if it can easily be made to apply to this situation.

Comment: The idea is this, consider binary reals. Chose real number $s_n$ such that, $s_n(n)=r(n)$. The only difficulty is that for example all $n$th values from $S$ are the same. Then you would have to move up the the first place where there is some variation, and encode the sequence in the turing machine, ah here is a problem, the machine is finite.

Comment: No ok here is the proof, there must be some $k$ such that there are infinitely many $s\in S$ such that $s(k)=0$ and infinitely many such that $s(k)=1$. Then just chosen$s_n$ such that $s_n(k)=r(n)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*For simplicity, by "real" I mean "infinite binary sequence;" there's a slight hiccup here vis-a-vis the dyadic rationals, but since Turing machines really act on the expansions of reals and not the reals themselves this is actually more appropriate.*

Note that there's an important subtlety when talking about using a countable set of reals as an oracle: you're not really using a countable *set* of reals, but rather a countable *sequence* of reals (e.g. when you say "all of the real numbers interlaced together," there are different ways to do this for the same set of reals).

Now this may seem benign, but it's definitely not:

> Suppose I have a countably infinite set $A$ of reals, and $r$ is an arbitrary real. Then there is some listing $(b_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ of $A$ such that $r$ is computable from the real $\bigoplus_{i\in\mathbb{N}} b_i$ (this is just the real you get by interlacing the $b_i$s together in order - that is, its $\langle m, n\rangle$th bit is the $m$th bit of $b_n$).

An earlier version of this answer gave a vastly over-complicated argument.

*Proof:* First, a bit of notation. Given distinct reals $s,t\in 2^\omega$, write $s\triangleleft t$ iff $s(n)<t(n)$ where $n$ is the **first point of difference** between $s$ and $t$. Note that we can computably in $s$ and $t$ determine whether $s\triangleleft t$ or $t\triangleleft s$.

Now fix some enumeration $(a_i)_{i\in\omega}$ of $A$, with all the $a_i$s distinct (we can do this since $A$ is infinite). We define a new enumeration $(b_i)_{i\in\omega}$ of $A$ by permuting adjacent pairs of $a_i$s in order to code $r$ into the "pattern of first differences." Specifically, say that $i\in\omega$ is **correct** iff $$r(i)=0\leftrightarrow a_{2i}\triangleleft a_{2i+1}.$$

Now define reals $b_i$ for $i\in\omega$ as follows:

- If $i$ is correct then $b_{2i}=a_{2i}$ and $b_{2i+1}=a_{2i+1}$.
- If $i$ is not correct then $b_{2i}=a_{2i+1}$ and $b_{2i+1}=a_{2i}$.

The sequence $(b_i)_{i\in\omega}$ is then an enumeration of $A$, and for each $i$ we have $$r(i)=0\leftrightarrow b_{2i}\triangleleft b_{2i+1}.$$ So $\bigoplus_{i\in\omega}b_i\ge_Tr$.

---

To address the second part of your question (which I forgot about), the answer is **no**, and there are many ways to prove this. For example, by transfinite recursion *(HINT: use the exact pair theorem)* we can define a $<_T$-increasing sequence of reals $r_\eta$ (for $\eta<\omega_1$) such that no $r_\eta$ computes (say) $0'$; since the sequences is $<_T$-increasing, this means no finite set of $r_\eta$s computes $0'$ either.

Actually, though, with a bit of work we can do much better. We can produce a perfect set (closed with no isolated points - all such have size continuum) of reals no finitely many of which compute (say) $0'$. Roughly, this works as follows. We want to build a function $F$ from $2^{<\omega}$ to $2^{<\omega}$ with the following properties:

- $\sigma\prec\tau$ iff $F(\sigma)\prec F(\tau)$.
- For all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ - and letting $\{\sigma_j: j<2^n\}$ list the binary strings of length $n$ - we have $$\Phi_n^{g_0\oplus g_1\oplus ...\oplus g_{2^n-1}}\not=0'$$ whenever $g_j\succ F(\sigma_j)$ (for $j<2^n$).

(Of course, we must show that such a tree exists, but it's not too hard - the key point being that $0'$ isn't computable, so we can't get "stuck" at any finite stage in the construction of $F$ since otherwise we'd be able to figure out what $0'$ is from finite information; note that this is *not* to say that $F$ is computable (it isn't).)

Given $f\in 2^\omega$, we let $f^*$ be the real $$\bigcup_{\sigma\prec f}F(\sigma);$$ our set $S$ will then be $\{f^*: f\in 2^\omega\}$.

Comment: Awesome, very clever.  This definitely answers the question for the countably-infinite case.  It's very interesting that $r$ can be computed by listing *any* countable set of real numbers in some order - it is not required to have an uncountable set at your disposal and the ability to choose your countable set.  Because this answers half of my question, I wish I could upvote twice or mark it as an answer while leaving the question open.  However, I will hold out until the finite case is answered as well.  (Thought about opening 2 math.SE questions, could still do it, not sure if I should).

Comment: @jcarpenter2 Whoops, missed that part. I've added to the answer to address it.

Comment: I've read the second part several times but I'm not understanding it.  What does the notation $\Phi_n^{g_0\oplus g_1\oplus ...\oplus g_{2^n-1}}$ mean?  Knowing that interlacing finitely many finite numbers in $\Phi$ always yields a finite number, why does $g_j$ have to be greater than $F(\sigma_j)$ for all $j < 2^n$?  Does $\prec$ refer to the usual ordering $<$ on real numbers?  Also, how does $\bigcup_{\sigma\prec f}F(\sigma)$ define a real number; why not combine them with $\oplus$ instead?

Comment: @jcarpenter2 The $g_i$s are *infinite binary sequences* (= reals for our purposes); "$\oplus$" is the "interlace" operation, and "$\Phi_e^h$" denotes the $e$th Turing machine with *oracle* $h$. $F$ is a function which outputs *finite* binary strings, and "$\prec$" means "is extended by" (e.g. $000\prec000000000...$"). $\bigcup_{\sigma\prec f}F(\sigma)$ defines a real number by expressing it as the union of finite initial segments. E.g. if $f=010101...$, maybe we have $F(0)=00, F(01)=001, F(010)=0011, ...$; then $F(0)\cup F(01)\cup F(010)=0011$, and continuing through $f$ builds a real. (contd)

Comment: Our uncountable set of reals is *exactly* the set of reals which can be "built from $F$" in this way; and the important property of $F$ is that it "forces" (this ultimately becomes a technical term!) the "weakness" property we want any finite collection of these reals to have.

Comment: Okay - I don't see how it's possible that $\Phi_n^{g_0\oplus g_1\oplus ...\oplus g_{2^n-1}}\not=0'$.  What's to stop you from choosing $g_0$ to be the real number prefixed with $F(\sigma_0)$, and then enumerating the halting set?

Comment: @jcarpenter2 " What's to stop you from choosing $g_0$ to be the real number prefixed with $F(\sigma_0)$, and then enumerating the halting set?" You can indeed do this, and such a $g_0$ will of course compute $0'$ - just, *not via program $\Phi_n$ specifically*. The idea is to at each stage "thin" the set of reals we're looking at, going "program by program."

Comment: It might be simpler to first consider the standard construction of a pair of Turing-incomparable sequences $f, g$. The key is the following claim. Suppose $\sigma,\tau$ are finite binary strings and $e\in\mathbb{N}$; then there is some $i\in\{0, 1\}$ and $\hat{\sigma}\succ\sigma$ such that the following condition holds: for any $g\succ\hat{\sigma}$, $\Phi_e^g(\vert \tau\vert)=1-i$. (Note that $\vert\tau\vert$, the length of $\tau$, is also the first term for which $\tau$ is undefined.) With this in hand, we can construct a pair of Turing-incomparable reals by finite extensions: (cont'd)

Comment: Let $\sigma_0=\tau_0=\emptyset$, and having defined $\sigma_n,\tau_n$, first apply the claim with $\sigma=\sigma_n, \tau=\tau_n, e=n$; note that any sequence extending $\hat{\sigma}$ cannot compute any sequence extending $\tau\langle i\rangle$ via program $\Phi_n$. Now do this again, only going "from $\tau$ to $\sigma$." Alternating this way, we ultimately build a pair of Turing-incomparable reals.

Comment: As to the proof of the claim two comments prior, there are two possibilities: (i) There is no string $g$ extending $\sigma$ such that $\Phi_e^g(\vert\tau\vert)$ halts. In that case, set $i$ to be whatever you want and let $\hat{\sigma}=\sigma$. (ii) There is some $g\succ\sigma$ such that $\Phi_e^g(\vert\tau\vert)$ halts, with output value $j$. Then let $i=1-j$, and let $\hat{\sigma}$ be the initial segment of $g$ used in the computation (or $\sigma$, whichever is longer).

Comment: @jcarpenter2 Your recent question reminded me of this one - did my edit address your questions? If not, I'll add more explanation. (I think this is an interesting question, I want to move it off the "unanswered" list.)

Comment: Thanks, I just came back to this and it does answer my question.  I don't entirely follow the extra discussion at the bottom, but I'll possibly ask more questions later.  I'm still very interested in Turing degrees, especially because they seem entirely useless (what's the point of reasoning about sets that aren't computable?)

Comment: @jcarpenter2 Well, there are surprising applications of Turing degrees outside of logic; see e.g. [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9711225.pdf). But ultimately I'd say the real reason for studying them, as for most things in math, comes from their intrinsic interest and beauty. It's not like Turing degrees are uniquely unrelated to the real world amongst mathematical notions, after all. (Separately, I just added a much simpler version of the first argument in my answer - not sure how I missed it originally!)